# Despite troubleshooting online messages will not sign in on one device

Tags: messages

I have 5 devices, all with imessage enabled.  I've associated my email and SMS number with them, but have recently deleted my phone number during troubleshooting the issue below (I'd like to only use it with email).

On my laptop only, running the messages app will initially ask for my email and password, then the sign-in process begins and never finishes.  If I go to settings I cannot sign out, because it is still waiting to sign in.  It stays like that between quitting and restarting messenger, and when rebooting.

I've followed guides online for troubleshooting this.  Some things I've tried are signing out on all my devices and signing back in, and deleting cache folders (under Library).

What could be the problem here?  Messaging seems to work fine on my other devices.

Comment: Which version of macOS is running on that laptop? Are you logged in in iCloud on it?

Comment: @nohillside 14.3.1, and part of my troubleshooting is logging out of iCloud then back in, as well as rebooting the computer.  At the moment I'm logged in to both